# User has Mortarboard but answered no questions

Tags: bug, badges

I see that [Michael](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/53102/michael) has the Mortarboard badge, but has asked and answered no questions. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user [also has the Good Answer badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/good-answer?userid=53102), but when you click through to it, it just says:

> (post deleted or otherwise unavailable)

Apparently, this user posted one really good answer that caused him to earn all those badges, but it was later deleted (perhaps along with the question it was posted for).  This caused him to lose all the rep gained from that answer, but not the badges, since those are permanent.

That's as far as I'm able to get with my limited rep here.  A ♦ mod or a user with 10k+ rep should be able to see the deleted answer and possibly provide further information.

Comment: For anyone who's interested, Michael posted [*"I would suggest using geese instead of dogs: goose, gander and gosling"*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129301/polite-alternative-to-the-term-bitch-when-referring-to-a-female-dog#comment267669_129301) as an "answer" to the question *"Polite alternative to the term 'bitch' when referring to a female dog"*. Before a mod got around to converting this "Not an Answer" into a comment, the wise voters of ELU had already awarded it **52 upvotes!** Sometimes I despair of this site.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I believe that question got on the Hot Network Questions list, so it's not just the local voters to despair of. Also, in context, it actually wasn't such a bad "outside-the-box" answer to the specific question asked; as the OP himself commented, "*Actually, this is an excellent idea. I got so fixated on dogs. I'd feel bad marking this as the correct answer, but this might be what I do for the example. Thanks!*"

Comment: Huh, that's unfortunate that it got converted to a comment, as I think it was actually an excellent answer to the question – and I took the same tack with my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, and so everyone who doesn't have enough rep to see deletions might marvel at how such a thing were possible. (I would have added this to Ilmari Karonen's post, but felt it would be presumptuous to do so.)

[image: deleted post]

Comment: The goose comment was badly worded, slightly inaccurate, and lacked explanation, otherwise, it was valid. It does not work with other birds. OED  Goose (n.):1.f. **A foolish person, a simpleton**.--1547   Certain Serm. or Homilies Against Contention ii, in J. Griffiths Two Bks. Homilies (1859) i. 138   *Shall I stand still, like a goose or a fool, with my finger in my mouth*? -- 1887   R. N. Carey Uncle Max xiv. 110   *What a goose I was to leave my muff behind me*.